# Need a CSS layout

Tags: css, layout

Being a CSS newbie, I m struggling to create a layout like this:

[image: Layout]

The left image and right text are center-aligned. Similarly, the right image and text are center-aligned. The right image gets into the empty space below the text.

Can anybody please help me with this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

My bad... I shouldnt have posted with sleepy eyes. Here is the source code I have.

`<html> <head> <title>CSS exercise</title> <style> body{background-color:gray; font-family:Lucida Handwriting ;font-size:large;} .leftPic{width:300; height:250;} .rightPic{width:300; height:225} .bottomText{display:block;} </style> </head> <body> <div> <img src="left.jpg" alt = "left image" class="leftPic" /> Left text </div> <div> Right text <img src ="Right.jpg" alt="right image" class = "rightPic"/> </div> <div> Bottom text </div> </body> </html>`

I agree with the negative vote. My apologies.
Josh, really appreciate your generosity.

Comment: Nobody will help you until you paste whatever code you have so far

Comment: I agree. You just can't ask for people to do the work for you. Learn, digg, google, try, experiment... then ask more specific questions. A hint: search for css float property.

Answer (score 3):

You know, normally I'm not this generous, but I feel you put enough work into the explanation to deserve an answer.

Here's a jsFiddle of your layout: http://jsfiddle.net/9UdLV/

Comment: Please post the code into the answer.  JSFiddles are notoriously unreliable.